# Apply css effect after link is clicked?

Tags: html, asp.net, css, colors, hyperlink

How can I apply a specific css scheme if the nav link clicked is `active`?

I tried many options `a:active`, `a:selection`, `a:link` - none of them work!

Basically, the nav link for the page clicked should be highlighted :)

Here is my **CSS**:

```
ul#menu{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li{
     display: inline;
     list-style: none;
     padding-left: 15px;
}

ul#menu li a{
    background: none;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:hover{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: "Basically, the nav link for the page clicked should be highlighted" — That isn't what "active" means. Active means "In the process of being clicked on".

Comment: maybe this will help you. http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/highlighting-current-page-with-css

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no CSS Pseudo class to add active attribute. However, create a new class named `active` and add it to either your `li` or `a` tag and give appropriate styles. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/2KMhW/)**.

**HTML markup**

```
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Link-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link-3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link-4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="active">Link-5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS markup**

```
ul#menu{
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li{
     display: inline;
     list-style: none;
     padding-left: 15px;
}

ul#menu li a{
    background: none;
    color: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:hover{
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li a.active{
    color:#333;
}
```

You can add `active` class dynamically through jquery

Comment: Don't call it active, that is just asking to be confused with `:active`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like :-

```
 ul#menu li a:active {
            color: #0000FF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

When setting the style for several link states, there are some order rules:

> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited
>   a:active MUST come after a:hover

Comment: `:active` means "being clicked" not "has an href attribute pointing to the current url". That won't do what the question is asking.

Comment: I did not get ..what are trying to say ..can you explain more Please??

Comment: sorry about the confusion - so when i click the page if the nav button for that page should be different because the link is open

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of `:target` (which only pays attention to the fragment identifier part of the URL), CSS provides no way to select anything based on the current value of the URL.

Put something unique on each page to identify which page you are on. Then use that to apply the CSS.

For example:

```
<li class="currentPage">
```